# Audio file not playing from document directory

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

i have an audio file located in Document Directory and its not playing but I didn't get any error or crash. I'm really stuck at this situation, referred many SO links but none of them solved my issue.

```
  var myPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    if let documentDirectoryURL: NSURL = urls.first {
    print(documentDirectoryURL)// File copied to this directory
    let soundURL = documentDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("09.mp3")
        do {
            myPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL)
            myPlayer.delegate = self
            myPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            myPlayer.play()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error.debugDescription)")
            // SHOW ALERT OR SOMETHING
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it enter into the brackets? (`if`)

Comment: yes,it enters if loop

Comment: did you double check the `soundURL` is a valid path and file/directory exists ?

Comment: Yes, File is exist.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify;

There are 2 standard ways to play an Audio file:

Record an Audio then export that into a file inside the App (Document Directory) with a completion handler. From there we can access that file from the document directory.

```
let settings = [
    AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
    AVSampleRateKey: 12000.0,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1 as NSNumber,
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.High.rawValue
]

do {
    audioURL = let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("recording.m4a")
let audioURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioFilename)
    audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioURL, settings: settings)
}

class func getDocumentsDirectory() -> String {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

And there is more that you do like the actual recording, etc. Here is a tutorial

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-record-audio-using-avaudiorecorder

--OR--

We have an audio on the computer, which you transferred to XCode and you can just call it using

```
myPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(fileURLWithPath: "09.mp3")
```

Comment: Its located in document directory not in the Xcode bundle dir.

Comment: Well how did it get there? Do you have code for that? Please post the code if you do

Comment: Haha, that's not exactly how that works. You have to actually export something into the documentDirectory or it will be nil. Give me a few minutes to change my post above to address this.

Comment: Actually, let me ask this. Where does "09.mp3" come from? Like, why is the name "09.mp3"?

Comment: Hey, I have copied 09.mp3 into "documentDirectoryURL". you got it?

Comment: Then I extended the path with file name, i.e.. soundUrl where it belongs

Comment: That doesn't copy 09.mp3 into the documentDirectory, that just asks for a FILE URL from the DocumentDirectory extension of "09.mp3".

Comment: dude I know that. First I got url form  "documentDirectory" then i copied file into that directory. Simulator directory will be same unless we delete the app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115615/discussion-between-impression7vx-and-jan).